# Faster alternative to SelectedOption to retrieve selected item on drop down menu?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to be able to retrieve the selected option from a drop down menu. I'm using the following code currently (Selenium and C#):

```
var selectName = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("Name"));
string name= selectName.SelectedOption.Text;
```

This works, but it's very slow (10+ secs) on drop down menus with lots of items (1000+). Are there any alternative approaches that would provide the results faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [implementation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ceaf3da79542024becdda5953059dfbb96fb3a90/dotnet/src/support/UI/SelectElement.cs#L88) of the `SelectedOption` property iterates over all options, and returns the one that is selected. The majority of the work is done by the client bindings in this case.

You could try to retrieve the currently selected `<option>` via CSS which is interpreted directly by the browser, chances are that that's faster.

For example:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select");
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Id("iframeResult")));

Console.WriteLine(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("select option:checked")).Text);

new SelectElement(driver.FindElementByTagName("select")).SelectByText("Saab");

Console.WriteLine(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("select option:checked")).Text);
```

Will yield `Volvo` and `Saab` respectively.

**Edit**: I quickly tried that out for a `<select>` tag with 10000 options of which the 400th option is selected:

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
Console.WriteLine(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("select option:checked")).Text);
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("CSS: {0}", sw.Elapsed);

sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
Console.WriteLine(new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.TagName("select"))).SelectedOption.Text);
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("SelectElement: {0}", sw.Elapsed);
```

Running the comparison in Chrome, the runtime difference is huge:

```
CSS:           00:00:00.0383144
SelectElement: 00:00:14.6210520
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've implemented this suggestion and it's working as expected and is, as you've illustrated, a great deal faster. I wonder what (if any) disadvantages there are of this approach?

Comment: The `SelectElement` class isn't really better, per se, it just makes working with SELECT elements easier by implementing several methods to select, deselect, etc. different OPTIONs. As long as the correct OPTION gets selected, it's all the same. In general I would use `SelectElement` because it makes things easier but in this case, selecting the OPTION directly due to performance issues is reasonable.